# canvas drawImage() - cut image in half and take left part

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, cut, drawimage

Image used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03HXV.jpg

Code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');  
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(media, canvas.width / 2, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

The result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xplPM.jpg

Is there a way to only get the left image and center it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the optional parameters of `drawImage`, by doing it this way your canvas can be at any size, so it should be:

`context.drawImage( media, 0, 0, media.width / 2, media.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

```js
var my_canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    context = my_canvas.getContext("2d");
    
let media = new Image();
media.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/5KYZ1M2.jpg';
media.onload = function() { 
  context.drawImage( media, 0, 0, media.width / 2, media.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200">
  This text is displayed if your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
</canvas>
```

You can read more information about `drawImage`[here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example in a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/dempad/pen/jOOjVbO?editors=1111), the canvas element is half the width of the image and then the image is aligned left & top. `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);`